# findall() returns empty string on html file in Python REGEX

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am learning Regex with Python and I am doing the baby names exercise of the Google Tutorial on Regex.  The html file --baby1990.html-- is in a zipped file that can be downloaded here: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/set-up ('Download Google Python Exercises')

The year is placed within  Tags.  The html code is the following:

```
<h3 align="center">Popularity in 1990</h3>
```

I am using the following code to extract the year from the file:

```
f = open('C:/Users/ALEX/MyFiles/JUPYTER NOTEBOOKS/google-python-exercises/babynames/baby1990.html', 'r')

strings = re.findall(r'<h3 align="center">Popularity in (/d/d/d/d)</h3>', f.read())
```

I have tested the pattern with RegularExpressions101 website and it works.

However the 'strings' list returned is empty.

len(strings)
out

Comment: Change `(/d/d/d/d)` to `(\d\d\d\d)` or `(\d{4})`

Comment: Please clarify. Does `findall` return an empty string, or an empty list? Or does it return a list containing one element, which is an empty string? Or something else?

Comment: FYI, using regexps to parse HTML is usually considered a very bad idea.

Comment: OK , somehow I messed up. I had tested the expression and I had found the error with regex101 but I did not pass the changes to the expression.  I am little bit tired.  Now, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to match a year in a contextual string is to use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) or [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

For instance:

```
import re

tag = """<h3 align="center">Popularity in 1990</h3>"""

mo = re.search(r"Popularity in (\d{4})", tag)
year = mo.group(1) if mo else ""

print(year)
# -> 1990
```

Or course, if you want to find all matches, you need to use `re.findall`
…

You check your Python RegEx, you can also try online with https://regex101.com/